# WINAPI: how to get edit's text to a std::string?

Tags: c++, string, winapi, edit

I'm trying the following code:

```
int length = SendMessage(textBoxPathToSource, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0);
LPCWSTR lpstr;
SendMessage(textBoxPathToSource, WM_GETTEXT, length+1, LPARAM(LPCWSTR));
std::string s(lpstr);
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi what length variable value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using it absolutely incorrectly:

First, you are passing a type instead of a value here:
`SendMessage(textBoxPathToSource, WM_GETTEXT, length+1, LPARAM(LPCWSTR));`

Interfacing WinAPI functions who write to a string requires a buffer, since std::string's cannot be written to directly.
You need to define a space to hold the value:
`WCHAR wszBuff[256] = {0};` (of course you could allocate the storage space using new, which you didn't, you just declared `LPCWSTR lpstr`).
Extract the string and store in that buffer:
`SendMessage(textBoxPathToSource, WM_GETTEXT, 256, (LPARAM)wszBuff);`
and perform `std::wstring s(lpStr)`.

EDIT:
Please note the use of std::wstring, not std::string.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reponse. However I'm getting this error when converting to std::string: "cannot convert from WCHAR[256] to const std::basic_string". And did you mean std::string s(wszBuff), not std::string s(lpStr)?

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. I'm a .NET developer, but I need to use WINAPI for this one program. You saved me :)

Comment: I think you need to use `SendMessageW` if you want `WM_GETTEXT` to retrieve UTF-16.

Comment: @jamesdlin, no it's done automaticalaly by Visual Studio as I have UNICODE defined.

Comment: If you're compiling with `UNICODE`, then your answer should specify that, or you should be using `TCHAR` and not `WCHAR`.  Is it is, your code would compile fine without `UNICODE` but would silently misbehave.

Answer (score 0):

What ALevy said is correct, but it'd be better to use a `std::vector<WCHAR>` than a fixed-size buffer (or using `new`):

```
std::wstring s;
int length = SendMessageW(textBoxPathToSource, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0);
if (length > 0)
{
    std::vector<WCHAR> buf(length + 1 /* NUL */);
    SendMessageW(textBoxPathToSource,
                 WM_GETTEXT,
                 buf.size(),
                 reinterpret_cast<LPCWSTR>(&buf[0]));
    s = &buf[0];
}
```